# value of the sum $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r^2+r}{n^3+r}$

Tags: limits

> The value of the sum $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r^2+r}{n^3+r}$

what i try

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\frac{1^2+1}{n^3+1}+\frac{2^2+2}{n^3+2}+\frac{3^2+1}{n^3+3}+\frac{4^2+1}{n^3+4}+\cdots +\cdots +\frac{n^2+n}{n^3+n}\bigg)$

$\displaystyle n^3+1>1^2+1\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^3+1}<\frac{1}{1^2+1}$

$\displaystyle n^3+2>2^2+2\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^3+2}<\frac{1}{2^2+2}$

.....

....

$\displaystyle \displaystyle n^3+n>(n-1)^2+n-1\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^3+n}<\frac{1}{(n-1)^2+n-1}$

did not understand how do i solve from here

help me please

Comment: That's a limit, not a sum.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r}{n^3 + r} \ge \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r}{n^3 + n} = 
\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{3(n^2+1)}$$
and
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r}{n^3 + r}
\le \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r}{n^3} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{3n^2}.$$
By the squeeze theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r^2+r}{n^3 + r} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The linear terms in $r$ don’t survive the limit, as they are either summed to terms merely quadratic in $n$ or divided by another factor of $n^3$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r^2+r}{n^3+r}
&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r^2+r}{n^3}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac r{n^3}}
\\
&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^3}\sum_{r=1}^n(r^2+r)\left(1+O\left(\frac r{n^3}\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^3}\left(\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+O\left(n^2\right)\right)
\\
&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^3}\sum_{r=1}^nr^2
\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^3}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6
\\
&=&
\frac13\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would care to comment?

Comment: Two downvotes now – if you're thinking of adding a third, I would really appreciate if you let me know what's wrong with the answer :-)